# "Server application, source file, or item cannot be found" error when trying to change text wrapping on image in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Editing a word document, when I try to switch a particular image from "Tight" text wrapping to "In Line with Text" wrapping, I get the error "Server application, source file, or item cannot be found. Make sure the application is properly installed, and that it has not been deleted, moved, renamed, or blocked by policy." There are numerous other images in the document that I have been able to do this with without any errors, so the problem is not with the document as a whole but something about this particular object.

I am using Word for Mac (16.54); the document was created on a PC. I do not have access to the original source image. If I copy the image and paste it to a new document, and the problem persists in the new document.

I can edit the wrap boundary as a workaround so it looks acceptable, but I want to be able to format all the graphics consistently.

Comment: I suggest you save the image to you local machine, then insert it to one document for a test.

Comment: I am not able to, and trying to do this, I think I might have figured out the problem. It doesn't look like a picture in its right-click menu, it looks like a *comment*.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem on MacOS when trying to insert an object (txt file) to docx. I searched and found that

> Object Linking & Embedding [OLE] primarily is a Windows OS technology
> which never has been fully implemented on Macs. In fact, it is
> severely restricted.
>
> The only file types that can be embedded as objects [other than image
> files inserted as Pictures] are those listed on the main pane when you
> go into the Insert> Object dialog window... Essentially, those created
> by Word & Excel - note that even PowerPoint files are excluded.

according to answers on [Cannot insert excel /txt /any files into word 2016 in mac](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cannot-insert-excel-txt-any-files-into-word-2016/0ad53707-442a-456d-ab49-6b0509778d79) and https://answers.microsoft.com/zh-hans/msoffice/forum/all/mac-office365/71e167c0-ec5e-4016-93f5-1576bff22dff which was answered in Chinese.